# Lag function with Override

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Original data -

| Key | Id | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1.006212 |
| A | 2 | 1.006241 |
| A | 3 | 1.007861 |
| A | 4 | 1.008858 |
| A | 5 | 1.008788 |
| A | 6 | 1.008858 |
| A | 7 | 1.008639 |
| A | 8 | 1.00512 |
| A | 9 | 1.00312 |

Logic - IF(Value < Previous Value) then Value else New Value)),1)

IF the previous Value is greater than the current Value THEN keep the current Value, ELSE it takes the previous Value.

Query used-

```
With abc as
(
Select Id , LAG(Value) ignore nulls
        OVER (PARTITION BY Key
              ORDER BY Id ) 
                        AS LAG_Value from table),
Select Id, Value,
CASE 
        WHEN (LAG_Value IS NULL ) THEN Value
        WHEN (LAG_Value >= AGE_TO_ULTIMATE_NO) THEN Value
        WHEN LAG_Value < Value THEN LAG_Value
        ELSE 1
    END AS NEW_AGE_TO_ULTIMATE
From abc;
```

Output -

| Id | Value | New Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.006212 | 1.006212 |
| 2 | 1.006241 | 1.006212 |
| 3 | 1.007861 | 1.006241 |
| 4 | 1.008858 | 1.007861 |
| 5 | 1.008788 | 1.008858 |
| 6 | 1.008858 | 1.008788 |
| 7 | 1.008639 | 1.008858 |
| 8 | 1.00512 | 1.00512 |
| 9 | 1.00312 | 1.00312 |

But correct data should be like below -

| Id | Value | New Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.00621 | 1.00621 |
| 2 | 1.006241 | 1.00621 |
| 3 | 1.007861 | 1.00621 |
| 4 | 1.008858 | 1.00621 |
| 5 | 1.008788 | 1.00621 |
| 6 | 1.008858 | 1.00621 |
| 7 | 1.008639 | 1.00621 |
| 8 | 1.00512 | 1.00512 |
| 9 | 1.00312 | 1.00312 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> IF the previous Value is greater than the current Value THEN keep the current Value, ELSE it takes the previous Value.

This kind of logic does not require `LAG`/`LEAD` and could be implemented with windowed `MIN`:

```
SELECT *, MIN(Value) OVER(PARTITION BY KEY ORDER BY Id) AS NewValue
FROM abc
ORDER BY Id;
```

Output:

[image]